# How do I expose related data through a WCF Data Service?

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

I have been reading through Alex D. James three year old blog posts as found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/02/24/creating-a-data-service-provider-part-8-relationships.aspx

It is a wonderful blog series about exposing custom data through WCF Data Services. In the 8th post titled "Relationships" he talks about how to describe and expose related data. The problem with the post as pointed out by the one commenter is that he does it in memory, but does not explain how to dynamically supply related data.

Using his example, I would like to fetch my "Products" dynamically through a database for instance. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a custom IQueryable implementation. The WCF DS Server will construct a LINQ query which describes the query (including all expansions and accesses to all the properties). With custom implementation you can translate such query to whatever you want. Or you can overwrite the query evaluation (GetEnumerator and enumerator execution) to retrieve the related data from somewhere.

Note that this is definitely not a trivial task. I wrote a series of blog posts about the LINQ expression trees which are generated and what each part means. You would need to at least partially recognize these in your code to implement the delay loading of related properties.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vitek/archive/2010/02/25/data-services-expressions-part-1-intro.aspx

Comment: Thank you Mr. Karas, it was your post on some other forum that turned me onto Mr. James' post. I was half worried that these posts may be out of date.

Comment: I have now read through the first four posts and I do not think that this is what I need. What I did not mention is that my query-root will be a previously constructed LInQ to EF. In such a case, do I still need to create my own IQueryable or or will this do? Also, after re-reading Mr. James' post, I think I missed something that was not very clear about how relationships work. Is it the case that the AssociationSet's tell WCF Data Services to go fetch a different query-root for the associated type? If so, it all makes sense to me.

Comment: Hi, its me again. I have finished your blog series and it is the last blog that I was looking for. Thanks for writing this.

Comment: WCF DS will call GetResourceSetQueryRoot only once per query (it will be for the root at the beginning of the path). Everything else is just part of the LINQ expression tree. If you want EF to resolve the navigation properties, then you don't strictly need custom IQueryable. Although there will be queries which won't work as the LINQ generated for custom metadata providers than when it's running against EF directly. As a result some queries don't work (incompatibilities between LINQ providers). It is fixable with rewriting the LIQN expression tree though.